# Dirac delta correlated white noise 3 time points

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes, noise

If I know that there is a noise which is delta correlated that is $\langle f(t)f(t') \rangle =\delta(t-t')$, can I say something about  $\langle f(t)f(t')f(t'') \rangle $?

Comment: Is the noise gaussian with zero mean? Then the above average is zero. Otherwise just from second moment of a probability distribution, you can not infer anything about all other moments.

Answer (score 0):

If the noise is Gaussian, you can use Isserlis' theorem (AKA Wick's probability theorem) to calculate moments of any order. Wick's theorem lets you express moments of any order (3 in the above case) for a Gaussian distribution as a sum of second-order moments (which we know).

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Isserlis%27%20theorem,is%20named%20after%20Leon%20Isserlis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Isserlis%27%20theorem,is%20named%20after%20Leon%20Isserlis).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).